# Loopback to input if number is entered

Tags: python

I am brand new to python and the tutorial videos I am watching don't seem to be addressing my question.

Basically I want the user to enter their first name and last name and then display the first and last name together. Simple enough

```
var1= input("First name")
var2= input("Last name")
print(var1, var2)
```

But if the user enters an integer instead of a string I want the program to loopback and re-ask for the name again.

Any advice would be great or even a link to a tutorial that shows examples of this.
thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a loop to keep asking for names if the entered name is invalid (using [isalpha()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.isalpha) method to determine if the string contains non alphabet characters):

```
var1= input("First name")
# keep asking for a first name if var1 has non alphabet chars
while not var1.isalpha():
    var1= input("First name")

var2= input("Last name")
# keep asking for a first name if var2 has non alphabet chars
while not var2.isalpha():
    var2= input("Last name")

print(var1, var2)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def contains_digits(s):
   return any(char.isdigit() for char in s)
```

this statement will return True if a string contains a number, false if it consists of anything other than numbers.

```
var1 = input("First Name")
if (contains_digits(var1)) == True:
    print("Are you are a robot??")
    sys.exit(1)
else:
   pass
```

Now do the same for var2.

I hope I helped